# How to wait for test execution to finish in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I have a test framework in Selenium Java where I run the test as a TestNG project.

Now, I have flags set in excel sheet as Y or N where it reads every Y row and gets the corresponding data, logs in with that data and opens up an .exe file.

The problem I have is as soon as the .exe opens up, the code reads the next Y flag and reads the data. What i want to so is to read the first Y from excel,, execute the test case and then read the next Y flag and so on.

Any suggestion would be of great help. Thanks!!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I think this might not the problem of java code. But for suggestion you can use Thread.sleep(milisecond); This will helps you to pause for sometime.

Comment: I have already done it, not working

Comment: please post the code